# Angular click not passing variables though

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have been struggling with an angular-js problem, I am unable to figure out why my ng-click is not sending through any values to the jquery function that is hooked up to it. It triggers the jquery fine, but when it comes into the jquery no variables comes with it!

So some information first of all:

I am using **angular-bootstrap-calendar** [Link to Project](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) (This is what I am having issues with)

Using **angular-bootstrap-calendar** I have implemented a custom day template using instructions from github [Instruction Page](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/blob/master/src/templates/calendarWeekView.html#L21)

The ng-click triggers my code correctly though no information is passed from the click to my customer event.

```
 <span data-cal-date
    ng-click="vm.calendarCtrl.dateClicked(day.date)"
    class="pointer btn"
    id="openDay"
    ng-bind="day.dayLabel">
 </span>

 <mwl-calendar events="vm.events"
      view="vm.calendarView"
      view-title="vm.calendarTitle"
      view-date="vm.viewDate"
      on-event-click="vm.eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
      on-event-times-changed="vm.eventTimesChanged(calendarEvent); calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
      edit-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>'"
      delete-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove\'></i>'"
      on-edit-event-click="vm.eventEdited(calendarEvent)"
      on-delete-event-click="vm.eventDeleted(calendarEvent)"
      cell-is-open="vm.isCellOpen"
      day-view-start="06:00"
      day-view-end="22:00"
      day-view-split="30"
      cell-modifier="vm.modifyCell(calendarCell)"
      on-view-change-click="vm.dateClicked(day)">      
 </mwl-calendar>

vm.dateClicked = function (day) {

    alert("Do Something");

};
```

**Results**

day = undefined

**Versions:**

```
"angular-bootstrap-calendar": "0.19.3",
"angular": "1.5.0",
"font-awesome": "4.5.0",
"moment": "2.12.0",
"interact.js": "1.2.6",
"angular-bootstrap": "1.2.4",
"angular-touch": "1.5.0",
"angular-animate": "1.5.0",
```

**Full Code Examples**

> ManRoster.cshtml

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-12 panel panel-default">
        <div ng-app="UserCal" class="textfix">
            <script id="calendarWeekView.html" type="text/ng-template">
                <div class="cal-week-box" ng-class="{'cal-day-box': vm.showTimes}">
                    <div class="cal-row-fluid cal-row-head">

                        <div class="cal-cell1" 
                             ng-repeat="day in vm.view.days track by $index"
                             ng-class="{
                                'cal-day-weekend': day.isWeekend,
                                'cal-day-past': day.isPast,
                                'cal-day-today': day.isToday,
                                'cal-day-future': day.isFuture}"
                             mwl-element-dimensions="vm.dayColumnDimensions"
                             mwl-droppable
                             on-drop="vm.eventDropped(dropData.event, day.date)">

                            <div id="resourcescount">
                                {{ day.events.length }}
                            </div>

                            <span ng-bind="day.weekDayLabel">
                            </span>
                            <br>
                            <small>
                            <span data-cal-date
                                    ng-click="vm.calendarCtrl.dateClicked(day.date)"
                                    class="pointer btn"
                                    id="openDay"
                                    ng-bind="day.dayLabel">
                            </span>
                            </small>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="cal-day-panel clearfix" ng-style="{height: vm.showTimes ? (vm.dayViewHeight + 'px') : 'auto'}">
                        <mwl-calendar-hour-list day-view-start="vm.dayViewStart"
                                                day-view-end="vm.dayViewEnd"
                                                day-view-split="vm.dayViewSplit"
                                                day-width="vm.dayColumnDimensions.width"
                                                view-date="vm.viewDate"
                                                on-timespan-click="false"
                                                ng-if="vm.showTimes">
                        </mwl-calendar-hour-list>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="cal-row-fluid"
                                     ng-repeat="event in vm.view.events track by event.$id">

                                    <div ng-class="'cal-cell' + (vm.showTimes ? 1 : event.daySpan) + (vm.showTimes ? '' : ' cal-offset' + event.dayOffset) + ' day-highlight dh-event-' + event.type + ' ' + event.cssClass"
                                         ng-style="{
                                              top: vm.showTimes ? ((event.top + 2) + 'px') : 'auto',
                                              position: vm.showTimes ? 'absolute' : 'inherit',
                                              width: vm.showTimes ? (vm.dayColumnDimensions.width + 'px') : '',
                                              left: vm.showTimes ? (vm.dayColumnDimensions.width * event.dayOffset) + 15 + 'px' : ''
                                            }"
                                         data-event-class
                                         mwl-draggable="event.draggable === true"
                                         axis="vm.showTimes ? 'xy' : 'x'"
                                         snap-grid="vm.showTimes ? {x: vm.dayColumnDimensions.width, y: 30} : {x: vm.dayColumnDimensions.width}"
                                         on-drag="vm.tempTimeChanged(event, y)"
                                         on-drag-end="vm.weekDragged(event, x, y)"
                                         mwl-resizable="event.resizable === true && event.endsAt && !vm.showTimes"
                                         resize-edges="{left: true, right: true}"
                                         on-resize-end="vm.weekResized(event, edge, x)">

                                        Shift


                                        <strong ng-bind="(event.tempStartsAt || event.startsAt) | calendarDate:'time':true" ng-show="vm.showTimes"></strong>

                                        <a href="javascript:;"
                                           ng-click="vm.onEventClick({calendarEvent: event})"
                                           class="event-item"
                                           ng-bind-html="vm.$sce.trustAsHtml(event.title)"
                                           uib-tooltip-html="event.title | calendarTrustAsHtml"
                                           tooltip-placement="left"
                                           tooltip-append-to-body="true">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                            <div id="ResourceInfo">
                                This will be the select panel
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </script>

            <!-- This is the end of the testing script -->

            <div ng-controller="Cal as vm">
                <h2 class="text-center">{{ vm.calendarTitle }}</h2>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">

                            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                    mwl-date-modifier
                                    date="vm.viewDate"
                                    decrement="vm.calendarView">
                                Previous
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default"
                                    mwl-date-modifier
                                    date="vm.viewDate"
                                    set-to-today>
                                Today
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                    mwl-date-modifier
                                    date="vm.viewDate"
                                    increment="vm.calendarView">
                                Next
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br class="visible-xs visible-sm">

                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'year'">Year</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'month'">Month</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'week'">Week</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'day'">Day</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <br>

                <mwl-calendar events="vm.events"
                              view="vm.calendarView"
                              view-title="vm.calendarTitle"
                              view-date="vm.viewDate"
                              on-event-click="vm.eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
                              on-event-times-changed="vm.eventTimesChanged(calendarEvent); calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
                              edit-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>'"
                              delete-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove\'></i>'"
                              on-edit-event-click="vm.eventEdited(calendarEvent)"
                              on-delete-event-click="vm.eventDeleted(calendarEvent)"
                              cell-is-open="vm.isCellOpen"
                              day-view-start="06:00"
                              day-view-end="22:00"
                              day-view-split="30"
                              cell-modifier="vm.modifyCell(calendarCell)"
                              on-view-change-click="vm.dateClicked(date)">      
                </mwl-calendar>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> ManRoster.js

```
angular.module('UserCal', ['mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])
    .controller('Cal', populateCal);


function populateCal($http, calendarConfig) {
    var resultset = [];
    var userID = 1;
    var vm = this;
    calendarConfig.templates.calendarWeekView = 'calendarWeekView.html';

    vm.calendarView = 'week';
    vm.viewDate = new Date();
    vm.events = [];
    vm.isCellOpen = true;

    vm.toggle = function ($event, field, event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        event[field] = !event[field];
    };


    vm.dateClicked = function (day) {

        alert("Do Something");

    };

}
```

[Plunker As Requested](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xe4bkLrpW9oDGGSfVoBz?p=preview)

Comment: Where is calendar control? I only see a controller called 'Cal' here. Could you create a plunker? (https://plnkr.co/) with a sample of what you are doing? I am missing pieces here.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xe4bkLrpW9oDGGSfVoBz?p=preview - I have put in on the question too. This is pretty close to what I am doing. If you click the date etc "29th May" - It should be passing the day.date but no love

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this one. I've created a custom directive to capture click events, it seems to be capturing the date consistently for me.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1XlQkgj5eJeuy728bEwI?p=preview

Add a directive (i just called it testDirective):

```
angular.module('UserCal', ['mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])
    .controller('Cal', populateCal)
    .directive('testDirective', testDirective);
```

*emphasized text*

```
function testDirective() {
      return {
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
          angular.element(elem).on('click', function (evt) {
            alert('You clicked on: ' + scope.vm.viewDate)
          });
        }
    };
}
```

Add it to the mwl-calendar element:

```
<mwl-calendar test-directive events="vm.events"
```

**Initial Idea:**

Alright, I think I have it now. In index.html, change

```
on-view-change-click="vm.dateClicked(date)"
```

to

```
on-view-change-click="vm.dateClicked(this.vm.viewDate)"
```

It should look like this:

```
<mwl-calendar
        events="vm.events"
        view="vm.calendarView"
        view-title="vm.calendarTitle"
        view-date="vm.viewDate"
        on-event-click="vm.eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
        on-event-times-changed="vm.eventTimesChanged(calendarEvent); calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
        edit-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>'"
        delete-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove\'></i>'"
        on-edit-event-click="vm.eventEdited(calendarEvent)"
        on-delete-event-click="vm.eventDeleted(calendarEvent)"
        cell-is-open="vm.isCellOpen"
        day-view-start="06:00"
        day-view-end="22:00"
        day-view-split="30"
        cell-modifier="vm.modifyCell(calendarCell)"
        on-view-change-click="vm.dateClicked(this.vm.viewDate)">
</mwl-calendar>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kKpjoCFvaR6xBjQL1bT6?p=preview

Comment: Close, that gets the date today, but if you click say the 8th it still returns 7th

Comment: Perfect, its doing what it should be doing! You win the points. If you are so inclined, do you have any clue how to stop it moving to the day view on click rather than just staying on the week view?

Comment: Never mind figured it out... this scope thing is quite handy!